# Understand weight in PyTorch convolution layer 1D

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am trying to understand the work of convolution layer 1D in PyTorch.
I use Conv1D(750,14,1) with input channels equal to 750, output channels are 14 with kernel size 1. As I understand, the weight in convolution layer is the kernel/filter so in this case, the weight dimension is 14x1. but when I print the weight, the dimension is 14x750x1.

Is my understanding about weight for convolution layer wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, convolution is performed in channel-wise fashion, in your case the number of input channels is 750, you requested 14 kernels of size 1x1 each.

That's why the weight tensor is `14x750x1` (14 kernels of size 1 "running" through the whole depth of 750 input channels).

Answer (score 1):

You defined a 1D convolution layer that has `14` filters each having `750` channels and a kernel size of `1x1`. This means that the weight of the overall layer is `14*750*1*1`, shaped `(14, 750, 1)`, while its bias has only 14 elements (one additive bias per filter):

```
>>> conv = nn.Conv1d(750,14,1)

>>> conv.weight.shape
torch.Size([14, 750, 1])

>>> conv.bias.shape
torch.Size([14])
```